# gitlab failed on swarm when i use nfs server as a volume keeper

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-volume, nfs, swarm

I have some issue with gitlab on docker swarm when i use nfs server as a volume keeper. its failed here:

> Recipe: gitlab::database_migrations
> ruby_block[check remote PG version] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
> rails_migration[gitlab-rails] action run[2024-02-05T06:12:38+00:00] WARN: gitlab-rails does not have a log_group or default logdir mode defined. Setting to 0700.
> bash_hide_env[migrate gitlab-rails database] action run
> [execute] Running db:schema:load rake task
> psql:/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/structure.sql:9: NOTICE:  extension "btree_gist" already exists, skipping
> psql:/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/structure.sql:11: NOTICE:  extension "pg_trgm" already exists, skipping

my docker compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    volumes:
      - /nfs/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab
      - /nfs/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - /nfs/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab
    shm_size: '256m'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: "from_file('/omnibus_config.rb')"
    configs:
      - source: gitlab
        target: /omnibus_config.rb
    secrets:
      - gitlab_root_password
    networks:
      - test
configs:
  gitlab:
    file: /nfs/gitlab/gitlab.rb
secrets:
  gitlab_root_password:
    file: /nfs/gitlab/root_password.txt
networks:
  test:
    external: true
```

and my gitlab.rb file:

```
external_url 'http://gitlab.test/'
gitlab_rails['initial_root_password'] = File.read('/run/secrets/gitlab_root_password').gsub("\n", "")
```

my nfs export:

```
/nfs/        *(rw,sync,fsid=0,crossmnt,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/nfs/shared  *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```